# PHP: Get Image gamma Value (of Pixel)

Tags: php, imagick

I have two similar Images, one of it is brighter than the other.
I tried to get a Color or Gamma-Value to handle with and found the following Imagick-method with no results (0):
As endresult i would like to adjust both Image in same brightness.
I expect a value like 0.5 or related. What is wrong?

```
<?php
$s1=new Imagick('01.jpg');
$s1->getImageGamma (); // Output 0
?>
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

JPG files store gamma corrected values i.e. the image data after the gamma value has been applied to it. They don't store the gamma value separately as all sRGB files are assumed to have a gamma of 2.2

The function is returning 0 by default to indicate it failed to get the gamma value from the image.

I would bet cash money, that you actually seeing a colourspace problem rather than a gamma problem. i.e. some of the images are actually Adobe RGB.